# $\bigodot=?$ for $(\sqrt 2) ^ \sqrt 3 \bigodot (\sqrt 3) ^ \sqrt 2$ where $\bigodot is \lt or \gt$

Tags: inequality

$\bigodot=?$ $(\sqrt 2) ^ \sqrt 3 \bigodot  (\sqrt 3) ^ \sqrt 2$  where $\bigodot is either \lt or \gt$

In other words, which one is larger $(\sqrt 2) ^ \sqrt 3$ or $(\sqrt 3) ^ \sqrt 2$?
The best I could do was ending up with $\sqrt \frac {3}{ 2} = \frac {\ln 3}{\ln 2}$

side question : is there a symbol like encircled $?$ for when what we are trying to find is the correct order symbol like one of $\lt,\leq,=,\geq , \gt $ ?

Hopefully using just juxtopisition of symbols without resorting to real analysis.
is it possible to do with precalculs algebra?

Comment: Use logarithms and their properties. For example, check whether $\;\frac{\log x}x\;$ is monotonic somewhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that since both values are positive, we can square both expressions without changing their ordering, so we can consider $2^{\sqrt3},\;3^{\sqrt2}$.

Now, this is obvious, since $\big(2^{\sqrt3}\big)^\sqrt3=8$ and $\big(3^\sqrt2\big)^\sqrt3=3^\sqrt6>3^\sqrt4=9$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $x\mapsto x^\frac{1}{x}$. Differentiate and check that the function is increasing on $(0,e)$ and decreases after that, taking global maximum value at $e$. Therefore,
$$\sqrt{3}^\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}>\sqrt{2}^\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\iff \sqrt{3}^\sqrt{2}>\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{3}$$

**EDIT**

The OP has edited his question to reject calculus based methods. Another method would be to see
$$(\sqrt{3}^\sqrt{2})^\sqrt{2}=3$$
$$>2\sqrt{2}$$
$$=(\sqrt{2})^3$$
$$>\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{6}$$
$$=(\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{3})^\sqrt{2}$$
or alternatively,
$$(\sqrt{3}^\sqrt{2})^\sqrt{3}>\sqrt{3}^2$$
$$=3$$
$$>2\sqrt{2}$$
$$=(\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{3})^\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: Can you draw this conclusion even if $2<e<3$?

Comment: @dfnu, I am applying the function on values $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$, both of which are less than $e$.

Comment: my bad sorry! Thanks